# Is there any issue, if firebase cloud functions run multiple times (without writing hitting firestore db)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need a bit of expert advice. I'm using the firebase cloud function to automate few things ( using this brilliant nodejs package "https://github.com/jdgamble555/adv-firestore-functions".

What happens is, it runs on - onWrite trigger, as I understand when onWrite triggers, it executes the function on each new document or childnode within a document being updated or created or deleted. That package has taken care many of things, but my concern is, executing the functions multiple times does any harm? I'm already making sure than if not required do not hit firestore by using condition checks. So (all) the function executes as I can see it in the log not writing/updating firestore db if not required.

I'm worried if all functions execute all the time will I finish my limits quickly. ( right now I'm testing on Firebase emulator), specially when userbase with increase.

Anything can be done to reduce these calls or its normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the firebase documentation, the first 2 million invocations are free per month, after that 0.40$ for every million invocations. Also, there is a resource limit for each function call. https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#free_tier

As of my knowledge and experience, **this is normal**. Just make sure that your code does not make any infinite function calls & database reads/writes.
I'm also using cloud functions for my social media platform which also uses triggers to execute & write to the database based on conditions. It never went beyond the free quota.